# Проверка на уникальность в списке

Tags: python, list

Есть список:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
```

Какие существуют способы проверки чисел на уникальность,и какой способ является наиболее простым и понятным?

Comment: Что такое уникальность чисел в вашем понимании?

Comment: `len(a) == len(set(a))`.

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов проверить каждое число на уникальность в пределах списка - использовать метод `.count()`:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
for num in set(a):
    print(f'Число {num} {"" if a.count(num) == 1 else "НЕ"} уникальное в списке')
```

```
Число 1  уникальное в списке
Число 2  уникальное в списке
Число 3 НЕ уникальное в списке
Число 4  уникальное в списке
Число 5  уникальное в списке
```

Comment: Мне не совсем понятен алгоритм.Можно в несколько строчек написать условие после цикла пожалуйста?

Comment: тернарный if внутри {} ничего не подставляет в строку, если количество вхождений очередного числа равно 1, т.е. оно уникально, и подставляет в строку 'НЕ' в ином случае - когда количество вхождений числа в список более 1